# How to restart windows with outp(0x92,1)

Tags: winapi

I'm testing an app that should recover gracefully after power failure, for a number of diverse windows customer installations.

This particular app uses an proprietary database that I'm enhancing with crash-recovery capabilities.  Some day it will be re-engineered to use a robust standard database, but we are not there yet.

So my problem is how to simulate power failures to test the new recovery capabilities of the app.  Mind you that windows reboot is not enough, it must be hard restart without disk flush.

I found the C line "outp(0x92,1);", which seemed ideal, but even under administrator permissions it produces an exception "0xC0000096: Privileged Instruction" , doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: http://logix4u.net/parallel-port/16-inpout32dll-for-windows-982000ntxp

Comment: Hans, thanks: this dll seems great ... but, awkwardly, either the download link of the page is broken or I'm nuts ... Can you elaborate on how to download the dll or refer to some other download option ... please ?

Comment: Next google hit: http://www.programmersheaven.com/download/28409/Download.aspx

Comment: DLL inpout32.dll downloaded and ran OK, but still the pc doesn't reboot after calling **Out32(0x92,1)**.  Maybe the OS blocks such a request or the BIOS ignores it ...